# Car drives great but, after you shut off it won't crank for a few hours

Tags: starting

92 Plymouth Colt. New plugs; new fuel filter. Car runs great when you crank it and drive for a while, but won't start back until a few hours later. Car turns over fine, just won't start.

Answer (score 1):

Hot-start problems are indicative of loss of pressure in the fuel line. This is usually caused by a leaky fuel injector.

The reason why this happens only for hot starts is because the fuel is more likely to vaporize as temperature increases. In order to avoid vaporization problems the fuel lines are expected to be pressurized during a hot start. If there is a fuel leak then the fuel may have partially vaporized by the time it reaches the fuel injectors, preventing the injectors from sending fuel through to the combustion chambers.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the ignition key to the run position while listening for the fuel pump running for 2-5 seconds before it goes quiet again. You can also bridge the power fuse for the fuel pump with an amp meter to see if takes a feed, with the fuse removed, when turning the key to the run position. If you cant get a feed or hear the pump running you will need to test out the fuel pump relays, they can work intermittantly when starting to fail.